# Flutter Stack not aligning floating action button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm making a listview with a few buttons. I've used a stack widget to place two floating action buttons on top of Listview. However, I want to align them to the bottom right and bottom left of the listview. I'm not able to do this we Align widget although I don't understand why. Note that I understand I could've used a scaffold widget here but that is not an option given Listview is a child of Scaffold. Also, I've tried using the alignment property of Stack, but it didn't work. I was hoping you guys could help solve this problem :D
This is the code here:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      written = [];
      read = [];
    }

    return Stack(
        //fit: StackFit.expand,
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd,
        children: [
          ListView.separated(
              reverse: true,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              separatorBuilder: (context, i) => Container(
                    //color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 8,
                  ),
              itemCount: savedhistory.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) => Dismissible(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    onDismissed: (direction) {
                      setState(() {
                        savedhistory.removeAt(i);
                        updateString(i);
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                      child: savedhistory[i],
                      //padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    ),
                    /* read == null
            ? []
            : read.map((e) => ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(e),
                  subtitle: Text(e),
                )), */
                  )),
          Positioned(
              //alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              // child: GestureDetector(
              //     onLongPress: () => getString(),
              bottom: 50,
              right: 0,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.replay_outlined),
                  onPressed: getString,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green[200])),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Container(
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.download),
                  onPressed: addString,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green[200]),
            ),
          )
        ]);
  }
}
```

After using positioned there seems to be some space beyond which button gets clipped, I don't understand why though.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjrnL.png

Answer (score 0):

try to use Positioned widget :

```
stack(
  children[
    Positoned(
      bottom : 0
      left :1
      child: Container(
        /// YOUR CODE ///
            )
          )
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Hey, I've applied your solution but the problem still persists. There seems to be a little space inside which the button space can be placed. Beyond it, it gets clipped. I'm not sure I understand why. I've put the screenshot in the edited question

Answer (score 0):

first set `stack` widget's `alignment` to `bottomcenter` and then use `Positoned()` for first button widget with `left: 0` and with second button `right:0`